# onClick toggle class inside setInterval function

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

```
setInterval(function () {
$("#bound").click(function () {
    $(".top").toggleClass("one");
    $(".middle").toggleClass("two");
    $(".bottom").toggleClass("three");
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-show");
});}, 450);
```

What is wrong with it?
Transition lags too much and sometimes stops workin.

Comment: why setInterval?

Comment: Why are you using setInterval? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Like @Jai mentioned in his answer below, setInterval is binding too many `click` events which slows down your browser. So we need to know what your objective is to help you out

Comment: when i click menu icon it should wait for 450ms then trigger the toggleClass function, and it should wait for another 450ms when i click on the menu icon again.

Comment: @PraveenBisht okay then you would change as per my answer with `setInterval` it will get executed only once for each event.

Answer (score 0):

> *What is wrong with it?*

The thing is you are binding so many `click` events at the interval of 450ms which will lead the browser to consume so much memory and browser will be unresponsive eventually.

Other noticeable thing is that you will get the "n" the number of bound events. So, as it is a continued process so at each iteration it will bind an event means if two iterations then two callbacks execution.

I guess you might instead do this:

```
$("#bound").click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () { // <------change it to setTimeout if u don't make it infinite
        $(".top").toggleClass("one");
        $(".middle").toggleClass("two");
        $(".bottom").toggleClass("three");
        $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-show");
    }, 450);
});
```

Comment: putting the setInterval inside would trigger a infinite transition each of duration 450.

Comment: yes same thing happens to be as you are currently doing. Instead i suppose you might use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Incase you want the latency after click event, you should put `setInterval` function inside `click` function:

```
$("#bound").click(function () {
  setInterval(function () {
    $(".top").toggleClass("one");
    $(".middle").toggleClass("two");
    $(".bottom").toggleClass("three");
    $(".nav-menu").toggleClass("menu-show");
  }, 450);
});
```